# Show last MySQL record with an "and" before (MySQL loop)?

Tags: php

So I have MySQL query and it shows all Users which liked a post. It looks like this:

```
<?

echo 'Liked by&nbsp;';

$sql="SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE faved LIKE '%$idpost%'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '<a href="" class="link">'; echo $row['fullname']; echo '</a>';
echo ',';

}

echo '.';

?>
```

How can I now select the last looped entry and show an "and" before it and not an ","?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_num_rows() to count the number of rows that are returned before you start fetching the result, and in the while loop you add an increment variable and a test, if that variable is equal to the number of rows you echo and instead of ,

See : [mysql_num_rows documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)